# storing/passing delegates as variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I am fairly new to C# and was working on a a way to implement a dynamic GUI which uses the serial communication. I originally come from C, so the concept of function pointer is familiar.

Basically I want to invoke a answerFunction() function when the serial command has been processed.
In Theory:
I have a Class lbl_txtBox_Pair which is dynamically created on runtime.
I have a Class comObject which communicates with the serial Port.
I have a third class comPacket which holds all information regarding one serial command.

1. in an Object of Class lbl_txtBox_Pair I instantiate a Packet and tell it which function should be called when the serial command is finished.
2. I give the packet Object to the comObject Instance.
3. after being processed the comObject wants to signal the original sender of the packet by calling the delegate which is stored in the Packet Object.

For some reason I can't get it to work. It tells me that the Attribute of Packet is not callable. Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Here is the Code:
first the code in Class "lbl_txtBox_Pair". I create the comPacket here and give it to the comObject.

```
public delegate void answerHandler( comPacket packet);
public void txb_value_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
   {
      answerHandler answerMethod = new answerHandler(this.processAnswer);
      comPacket question = new comPacket(this.command, answerMethod, 1);
      comObject.addPacket(question);
    }
 }
```

The constructor of comPacket. Here the delegate gets stored to be called later.

```
public Delegate answerFunction;
public comPacket(string cmd, Delegate func, int prio)
{
    this.cmd = cmd;
    answerFunction = func;
    this.prio = prio;
}
```

In the comObject the Packets get processed. When finished I want to call the function stored in the Packet. The comObject runs in a different Thread by the way.

```
if (this.isEndtocken(inputline))
 {
    listen = false;
    packet.answerFunction(packet);
 }
```

And here it is were it breaks. packet.answerFunction(packet); wont execute and says it can't be called as Method.

Can anybody see where it goes wrong? I think it seems like the delegate looses the information that it is a delegate or something.
Or do I have to completely restructure the code to use other types of callback / Event Methods?

Comment: is this a compiler message or a runtime fail? could you please post the exact message you are getting?

Comment: BTW, if `funk` is just `Delegate`, you cannot call it with an argument. Perhaps you need `answerHandler` instead? (inside `comPacket`)

Answer (score 2):

Change your `comPacket` to take a strongly typed delegate:

```
public answerHandler answerFunction;
public comPacket(string cmd, answerHandler func, int prio)
{
    this.cmd = cmd;
    answerFunction = func;
    this.prio = prio;
}
```

If you still want to keep the delegate reference weakly typed, you can leverage `DynamicInvoke` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx

EDIT: Another option if you want to maintain strongly typed delegates yet have different usages is to leverage generics. Your delegate can be housed in a generic class and tie its signature against that generic type.

Comment: Thank you Chris,
What I did now is I 'm using strong Types. I cant't define the type of the delegate in the lbl_txtBox_Pair Class though because that way I could only use this type of delegate in this Class. Therefore it needed to be weak.
But when it is defined in the comObject Class, I can reference it in more Classes than lbl_txtBox_Pair.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment so I have to post this as an answer instead.
Delegates (and events and stuff) can usually only be "invoked" by the object that contains them.

So if you have

```
class MyClass {
    public event Action someEvent;
    // you can also replace Action with the name of your delegate type
}
```

and you try to do

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
x.someEvent.Invoke();
```

Then that's an error. If you want other objects to be able to invoke the event, you'll have do add a method to `MyClass` like this:

```
public void InvokeMyEvent() {
    someEvent.Invoke();
}
```

(I forget whether you still have to do this for static events)

Comment: This is only the case when you declare them with the `event` keyword. Delegates are simply objects that can be passed around and invoked willy-nilly. If you do not mark your delegate with `event`, it can be invoked by _anything_ that has access to it. At any rate, this isn't the issue happening with the question.